# Node mongodb: Error: connection closed due to parseError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Using the native 'mongodb' npm package, I'm receiving

```
Error: connection closed due to parseError
```

When making a very basic query:

```
 collections.myCollection.findOne({id: someID}, function (err, repo) {
    ...  
 })
```

The weird thing is, the exact same query has run before. Types are identical for each query, etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answering my own question to hopefully stop the next person from tearing their hair out:

As noted here, [this error message is useless and doesn't relate to the actual problem](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/13afhvp271/help-debugging-error-connection-closed-due-to-parseerror-with-native-node-driver). **The production Mongo driver throws away all errors in a catch block**.

To find what the error actually is:

- open your `node_modules/mongodb`
- find `server.js`
- look for `mongoReply.parseBody`
- log the `err` to see something actually useful.

In my case:

```
ReferenceError: collection is not defined
```

**Edit**: **Node MongoDB native 1.4 is now stable**, and includes a fix to this bug.

Comment: Thanks for the hour. I'll try to spend it wisely. In my case (twice now), I've traced it back to an unhandled exception in my callback code. Be sure to handle exceptions in your callbacks or they could get obscured by the calling context.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are using mongoose instead mongodb can check in the following location for the same.

`/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection`